# Pass value from one ASP.NET app to another via HTTP Header

Tags: asp.net, http, header

We are implementing a single sign on mechanism in an enterprise environment, where the token is shared between applications using HTTP header. Now, in order to do the integration test, I need to write an application to simulate this.

Is there any way in ASP.NET where I can redirect to another web-page and pass a custom HTTP header in the process?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a page on **Site B** that **Site A** redirects the user too that sets a cookie with the desired value.

for instance.

http://siteb.com/authenticate.aspx?authtoken=15128901428901428904jasklads&returnUrl=http://siteb.com/index.aspx

authenticate.aspx would set a cookie and then every request would receive authtoken.

Comment: ok, nice idea. but I am a little skeptical while using cookies. What if the client PC has cookies disabled, or even worse, if a  hacker wishes, he/she could manipulate the cookies.

Besides, I wish to simulate a test environment for a live system. The actual authentication happens via HTTP headers. In production, there is a setup where they use some gateway provided by CA Inc (not sure of the exact product name).

Comment: Your only option is to use Cookies or store it on the url, there is no way you can command a client to send custom http headers.

Comment: Also if your worried about cookies. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

And "hackers" can change http headers just as easy as cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The server could send the HTTP header to the client on a redirect, but the client would not send it back to the other remote server.

The ideal solution in this case would be to use a Cookie, or a QueryString variable. Cookies may suffer from cross-domain issues and become complicated if host names are different enough.

In any of these approaches, one must be careful not to create a security hole by trusting this information as it is user input coming back from the client (or some black hat).

Comment: Yeah.. its the server side implementation that I'm stuck with. How do I get an asp.net application to send custom HTTP header to another domain? I am looking at a solution where we redirect the control to another URL from the server, i.e maybe using Response.Redirect??

Comment: Yes, Response.Redirect if the data is small enough to encrypt, put the encrypted value on the QueryString (Forget headers).  Requires sharing keys from server A to server B. Synchronize the Machine Keys and use them to encrypt/decrypt the data. If that's not possible, or there is too much data, put a token such as a Guid on the QueryString. Then use a back-channel between servers where server B can call server A and ask it for the details of the incoming request. This type of custom solution is very error-prone, be sure to think of the attack vectors. Look at Windows Identity Foundation.